# Прямое соединение в Интернет между двумя устройствами

Tags: сеть

Как можно установить прямое соединение для передачи данных между двумя устройствами подключенных к Интернет? С учетом всевозможных закрытых портов и динамических IP.

Подозреваю, что это можно сделать с помощью сервера. Чтобы клиенты при запуске открывали сокет на сервер, а при необходимости сервер просто бы копировал данные из одного сокета в другой. Но тогда и соединение получается не прямым и скорее всего это повлияет и на скорость передачи данных, и даст нагрузку на сервер. А хотелось бы, чтобы устройства сначала зарегистрировались бы на сервере, а после этого уже обменивались данными напрямую. Это возможно?

Comment: если использовать ipv6 или настроить роутеры.